# How to retrieve an int array that is stored in a table using PROGMEM?

Tags: arduino

I'm new to Arduino and currently learn to use PROGMEM to store variables so that I can save dynamic memory. I have  13 variables including these three below that I store using PROGMEM.
Here are some of example of variables that I store and use it in my functions :-

```
const unsigned int raw_0[62] PROGMEM  = {2600,850,400,500,400,500,450,850,450,850,1350,850,450,450,400,500,400,450,450,400,450,450,450,450,400,450,900,850,900,850,900,450,450,850,900,850,900,850,450,450,900,450,400,450,400,900,450,450,450,400,450,450,450,450,400,450,450,450,450,400,450,};
const unsigned int raw_1[60] PROGMEM = {2600,850,450,450,450,450,450,850,450,850,1350,850,500,400,450,400,450,450,450,450,400,450,450,450,400,450,900,850,900,900,850,450,450,850,850,900,900,900,400,450,900,450,450,400,450,850,450,450,450,450,400,450,450,450,450,400,450,450,850,};
const unsigned int raw_a[100] PROGMEM = {3500,1700,400,450,450,1250,450,400,450,400,450,400,500,400,450,400,450,400,450,400,450,450,400,400,500,400,450,400,450,1300,400,450,450,400,450,400,450,400,450,400,450,400,500,350,500,400,450,400,450,1300,400,400,500,400,450,400,450,400,450,450,400,450,450,400,450,400,450,400,450,400,450,450,400,450,450,400,450,1250,450,400,450,400,500,400,450,400,450,400,450,400,450,400,450,1300,450,400,450,1250,450,};
```

Here is the table that store the variables. I learn this approach from Arduino website; https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PROGMEM .

```
const unsigned int* const myTable[13] PROGMEM = {
  raw_0, 
  raw_1, 
  raw_2, 
  raw_3, 
  raw_4,
  raw_5,
  raw_6,
  raw_7,
  raw_8,
  raw_9,
  raw_a,
  raw_b,
  raw_c};
```

My problem is, how do I retrieve these variables using PROGMEM such as raw_1 and raw_a ?
This is what I did but it did not work :-

```
unsigned int * ptr = (unsigned int *) pgm_read_word (&myTable [1]);
irsend.sendRaw(ptr,62,38);
```

Most of examples that I found, they use String or char datatype but in my case, I use array integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ptr` is also pointer to PROGMEM, so you have to read the value (or values in this case) by `pgm_read_word`. The [IR library](https://github.com/z3t0/Arduino-IRremote/blob/master/irSend.cpp) doesn't support that at all (I hope it's the correct one).

Anyway `sendRaw` implementation is this:

```
void  IRsend::sendRaw (const unsigned int buf[],  unsigned int len,  unsigned int hz)
{
    // Set IR carrier frequency
    enableIROut(hz);

    for (unsigned int i = 0;  i < len;  i++) {
        if (i & 1)  space(buf[i]) ;
        else        mark (buf[i]) ;
    }

    space(0);  // Always end with the LED off
}
```

And all used methods are public, so you can implement your own function to do the same:

```
void  mySendRaw (IRsend & dev, const unsigned int buf[],  unsigned int len,  unsigned int khz)
{
    // Set IR carrier frequency
    dev.devenableIROut(khz);

    for (unsigned int i = 0;  i < len;  i++) {
        if (i & 1)  dev.space(pgm_read_word(buf+i));
        else        dev.mark (pgm_read_word(buf+i));
    }

    dev.space(0);  // Always end with the LED off
}

// And usage:
mySendRaw(irsend, (const uint16_t*)pgm_read_word(myTable+1), 62, 38);
```

However the size of arrays should be stored somewhere too, so you can use something like:

```
byte cmd = 1;
mySendRaw(irsend, (const uint16_t*)pgm_read_word(myTable+cmd), pgm_read_word(myTableLenghts+cmd), 38);
```

Comment: I implemented your method but received an error when compiling it error: initializing argument 2 of 'void mySendRaw(IRsend&, const unsigned int*, unsigned int, unsigned int)' [-fpermissive]
invalid conversion from 'uint16_t {aka unsigned int}' to 'const unsigned int*' [-fpermissive]

Comment: I've added explicit casts, it should help.

Comment: It is working fine now after adding the explicit casts. I can't vote up because restriction of Stackoverflow (I'm a newbie in Stackoverflow). Thanks a lot.

Comment: But you can accept it a solution for your question.